# User can't put input for second variable. C++

Tags: c++

Whenever I run the program, I can only input a value for the first variable, `employeeName`, but when I hit enter after I input the value, I get a "press any key to continue" prompt. Can somebody please tell me what's wrong?

```
// Calculate how many hours an employee has worked

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{


    //Declare Named Constants
    int const HOURS_IN_WORK_WEEK = 40;
    int const HOURS_IN_WORK_DAY = 8;

    //Declare Variables
    int employeeName;
    int hoursWorked;
    int totalWeeksWorked;
    int leftoverFromWeeks;
    int totalDaysWorked;
    int leftoverFromDays;
    int totalHoursWorked;


    //Get Input
    cout << "enter employee name: ";
    cin >> employeeName;

    cout << "Enter total hours worked: ";
    cin >> hoursWorked;


    //calculate total weeks, days, and hours worked
    totalWeeksWorked = hoursWorked / HOURS_IN_WORK_WEEK;
    leftoverFromWeeks = hoursWorked % HOURS_IN_WORK_WEEK;

    totalDaysWorked = leftoverFromWeeks / HOURS_IN_WORK_DAY;
    leftoverFromDays = leftoverFromWeeks % HOURS_IN_WORK_DAY;

    totalHoursWorked = leftoverFromDays;

    //Output
    cout << employeeName << "worked " << hoursWorked << "hours or " << totalWeeksWorked << "week(s), " << totalDaysWorked << "day(s), and " << totalHoursWorked << "hours.";






    system("pause");


}//End Main
```

Answer (score 3):

What I presume happened is that you unknowingly entered a string for the employee's name. However, if you look at your declaration:

```
int employeeName;
```

The type of the variable is `int`! Change this to [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and use [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read a space separated full name (`std::cin` will stop reading at whitespace, meaning the rest of the input will be attempted to be stored in an `int`, leading to the same behavior that happened with the first variable).

The input code would now change to:

```
cout << "enter employee name: ";
getline(cin, employeeName);
```

Also, on a side note, you should read why using `system("pause")` is [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong) (Although it doesn't really matter for such a small program, it is useful knowledge).